# Activate specific panel in leftPanel in PDFNet Webviewer

Tags: javascript, pdftron, pdfnet

I remove 2 of the 3 panels of the leftPanel by using disableElements:

```
  setQuickBarPanelContents() {
    this.instance.disableElements(['notesPanel', 'notesPanelButton', 'outlinesPanel', 'outlinesPanelButton']);
  }
```

One of the removed panels is the default active one, so when leftPanel is now activated, the remaining panel(thumbnails) isn't active by default and shows up blank with the button on top. You need to press the button to activate and see the actual thumbnails in the panel.

I can't seem to find any way to (default) activate this panel through the PDFNet API. Am I overlooking something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you'd want to use is `setActiveLeftPanel`: https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/WebViewer.html#setActiveLeftPanel__anchor.

In this particular case you can call `instance.setActiveLeftPanel('thumbnailsPanel')`.

Comment: Looks like I missed it after all. Thanks.